# Two different selects are locking each other out

Tags: sql-server, odbc

We normally use SQL Server but have recently began testing with ODBC.

Our application runs up but locks itself.

I have tracked the queries down via Activity Monitor and what seems to be happening is that there is a select statement running on a table.  After that the other select statements are locked with the value lck_m_s.

If I kill the first query the others work and everything continues.

It works when we use DB-Lib but not when we use ODBC SQL Native Client ODBC.

Is there anything I can do to prevent these statements locking each other when we use ODBC?

I have tried using NOLOCK in the queries and this solves this issue but causes other ones.  One of my colleagues was told about an option to change in the connection settings which might resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the with no lock locking hint in your FROM clause:

```
From tablename with(NOLOCK)
```

Comment: That might fix the symptom but I am quite keen to understand what is causing the problem so make sure similar things do not happen again.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't use the nolock hint, selects cause row level locking.  I assume both queries access the same rows, hence the lock while one is executing.

Comment: Ah right - so ODBC would do this and SQL Server not?  (Sorry for the basic questions, I am not a database guy!)

Comment: When you say SQL Server do you mean the query console?  ODBC is just opening a connection to SQL Server and executing SQL.

Comment: I think they are just options on which drivers to use to access the database?  Does that make sense?  As in we are now testing the ODBC drivers and are getting this issue.

Comment: I just checked and the differences are that is it not working when we use ODBC SQL Native Client ODBC but does work when we use DB-Lib.

Comment: Not sure, have +1 to negate it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter it your using native client driver or the older ODBC driver or some other tool except the interface you use /may/ change the cursor type etc by default. I am not aware that the ODBC driver or native client driver do that.